# ModelType property unavailable on ASP.NET repeaters

Tags: asp.net, webforms

I was looking at this video (http://www.asp.net/web-forms/videos/aspnet-web-forms-vnext/aspnet-vnext-videos-strongly-typed-data-controls) and 55 secs into the video he types in a "ModelType" this is for strongly typed data, but I don't seem to have that on my repeaters, am I missing something here? I'm using Web Forms and .NET 4.5.

Comment: Take a look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11153460/repeater-control-doesnt-have-public-property-modeltype

Comment: Great, it has been renamed to ItemType. Thanks a bunch.